# Can we change the singular values of a matrix to create a positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix, is there a way, by changing its singular values, to transform it into a positive definite matrix?

I do a Singular Value Decomposition. I look at the singular values. If the matrix is not positive definite, then I change them to create a positive definite matrix.

How would I change them, and is there any theory saying how close the resulting matrix would be from the original matrix? No preference for norm.

A comment suggested that to the diagonal matrix with the singular values, I add $\mu I$, with $\mu>0$. This was my original proceadure, however for the following matrix this doesn't seem to work.

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.24215 & 1.6337 & -0.650968 & 0.635641 \\
 0.183443 & 0.0432606 & 0.130042 & -0.318818 \\
 -0.204386 & -0.435348 & -0.966572 & 0.506948 \\
 -0.321633 & 0.286963 & 0.587576 & 1.37028 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I add the identity matrix to the Diagonal matrix with singular values, i.e. I do $U(Diag+I)V^\intercal$ and I get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.79872 & 2.36397 & -0.976203 & 0.861808 \\
 1.00304 & -0.442107 & 0.434236 & -0.331093 \\
 -0.197866 & -0.914375 & -1.73106 & 0.938273 \\
 -0.457474 & 0.327607 & 1.05367 & 2.24358 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Which is not Pos.Def.

2nd Addition:

I take the original matrix $A$, and compute the diagonal decomposition of $(A+A^T)/2 =P \ \text{Diag}(\lambda_i) \ P^{-1}$. I transform all the non-positive eigenvalues into positive eigenvalues, by $\max(\lambda_i,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a positive number, and $\lambda_i$ is the i-th eigenvalue. Then I give as output the new matrix $P \ \text{Diag}(\max(\lambda_i,\mu)) \ P^{-1}$.

This seems to give a PD matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing a singular value of a matrix"?

Comment: @5xum I do a Sing.Val. decomposition, I look at the singular values. If the matrix is not pos.def., then I changed them to create a pos.def. matrix.

Comment: You can transform any matrix into a positive definite matrix: just change the original matrix into the identity matrix. Without being more precise about what you mean by "transform", the question isn't really meaningful. (For example, you outline a procedure in your comment; does that satisfy your requirements?)

Comment: A way is to add $\mu I$ to your matrix, with $I$ the identity matrix, such that $\lambda_i + \mu > 0$ for all $\lambda_i$, the $\lambda_i$ being the singular values

Comment: If you apply you modified matrix to a given $x$ vector, the error will depend on this vector. It is easy to calculate the error for such a given vector. You can deduce the error for the worst case ...

Comment: @Damien, I've tried that but I have a matrix where that doesn't happen... $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.24215 & 1.6337 & -0.650968 & 0.635641 \\
 0.183443 & 0.0432606 & 0.130042 & -0.318818 \\
 -0.204386 & -0.435348 & -0.966572 & 0.506948 \\
 -0.321633 & 0.286963 & 0.587576 & 1.37028 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

I compute the singular values, I add a multiple of the Identity matrix and then I check to see if it's positive definite.

Comment: @GregMartin I've added some more information to the question.

Comment: A possibility is to transform you original matrix in a symmetric one, i.e. a positive one: $B = (A + A^T)/2$

Comment: @Damien, I'd already done that... It doesn't make the resulting matrix PD, though.

Comment: Please look at my comment to Eric's answer, to get a matrix closer to the original one

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, it depends what definition of positive definite you use. One is that all the eigenvalues are positive, another is that $\langle A v, v \rangle \geq 0$ for vectors $v$ over the complex field.

In either case, you need positive eigenvalues. Singular values are nonnegative numbers, the $i$th largest of which is greater than or equal to the absolute value of the $i$th largest eigenvalue. Your singular values can't possibly detect if your matrix has positive eigenvalues, and you can't modify them to get positive eigenvalues.

The second definition requires that your matrix is self-adjiont. In this case,  the eigenvalues are very useful. Every self-adjoint matrix is unitarily diagonalizable as $A=UDU^*$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ as entries. Simply replace the negative entries of $D$ with zero and you get the best positive (semi)-definite approximation to $A$ (in the two norm).

In the non-self-adjoint case you can also modify your eigenvalues but, its not as clear to me how you would get a best approximation. One great thing about unitaries is that the two norm is invariant under conjugation by them.

Note that no negative definite matrix has a best strictly positive definite approximation since the set of strictly positive definite matrices is not closed.

Comment: The statement "a positive definite [matrix] must be self-adjoint" is wrong. Consider $A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1}$, whose eigenvalues are both $+1$. It's not the case that $A^t = A$. So it's not self-adjoint. In general, a matrix is pos definite iff its *symmetric part*, $\frac{A + A^t}{2}$ has all positive eigenvalues. See, for instance, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html.

Comment: @JohnHughes, so if I use the symmetric part, calculate the eigenvalues, and put them positive, then I'm sure to get PD matrix? All symmetric parts have real eigenvalues?

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer the original question; I was merely pointing out that **this** answer was based on a mistaken claim. Like Greg Martin, I don't really understand your question, so I can't say whether your description above, which is a little vague, is a correct answer.

Comment: Let us decompose the matrix in the sum of a symmetric part and an asymmetric part. Modify the symmetric part as proposed in answers. Don't modify the asymmetric part. Hope it will help this time. Sorry

Comment: @JohnHughes It really depends what you mean by a positive definite matrix. I would not consider your example positive definite since if you let $v=(i, 1)$ then $\langle A v, v\rangle = 2-i$. I should have clarified I was using this definition, and thinking over $\mathbb{C}$ but the author also should clarify what they mean by positive definite.

Comment: @JohnHughes I've added some more information. What do you think? I know it's vague, but I must be a bit pragmatic, due to a limitation of several resources, among them time.

Comment: I think, Eric, your revised answer needs some proofreading. "One is that all the eigenvalues are positive *definite*", "the $i$th [singular value] is greater than or equal to to absolute value of the $i$th *singular value*"...there may be others as well.

Comment: Thanks John. I think its cleaned up now. I did a very poor job at merging the old answer with a new one.

Comment: Well..there's still an "eigenvalue value" (2nd paragraph, 2nd sentence), but overall it looks better. Thanks for writing this nice clear answer.